# How to import 2d Objects to scene 3d in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am beginner in Unity3d, I have a game is creating with Scene 3d. I wanna import 2d objects (picture cartoon with *.jpg or *.png) to the Scene 3d in order to save performance. How to do this ?

More detail: My game is 3d but i don't wanna use all objects in game with 3d Objects to save performance. For some objects, I like to create 2d object (pictures) such as money, paper, leaf...Which best way help me to do this???

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The first thing you need to do is the make the image a sprite, you do this by selecting it in the project explorer and changing from texture to sprite then press apply.

Next create a empty gameobject (GameObject -> Create empty)

Next add a sprite renderer to the empty gameobject (Component -> Rendering -> Sprite Renderer)

Next add the sprite to the sprite renderer.

Not sure how well it will work to mix 2d and 3d objects like this, if it doesnt work you can always just create a quad (GameObject -> Create Other -> Quad) and add the image as a texture like if its a 3d object.